# SQL Azure: "The instance of SQL Server you attempted to connect to requires encryption but this machine does not support it"

Tags: linq-to-sql, azure-sql-database, azure-worker-roles

I'm getting the following SQL exception intermittently when my Azure worker role is trying to connect to an Azure SQL Database to call ExecuteCommand, using LINQ-to-SQL:

> "The instance of SQL Server you attempted to connect to requires encryption but this machine does not support it."

Google seems to know nothing about this error message. The stack trace shows it's failing during the pre-login handshake:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The instance of SQL Server you attempted to connect to requires encryption but this machine does not support it.
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ConsumePreLoginHandshake(Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean&amp; marsCapable)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean withFailover)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlConnectionManager.UseConnection(IConnectionUser user)
at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.get_IsSqlCe()
at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.InitializeProviderMode()
at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.ExecuteCommand(String command, Object[] parameters)
```

I've found reports of other, similar errors that were due to various issues in the pre-login handshake (wherein it just fell back to a similar error message for any problem in the handshake), and others where the SQL Server "Force Encryption" setting needed to be changed, but since this is an Azure SQL Database I can't go in and change this setting in SQL Server and don't really expect I would need to.

Since I can't find anything else on this specific error, and it's not happening every single time, I'm not sure where to look. Any pointers as to where to look from here?

EDIT: Until shown otherwise, I'm chalking this one up to transient errors due to heavy traffic on the DB server from another one of my hosted services. Details in a follow-up question I asked: [Can two Azure SQL databases on the same server affect each other's performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18790234/can-two-azure-sql-databases-on-the-same-server-affect-each-others-performance)

Comment: You can specify encryption in the connection string, while not a server setting you can see if that helps (turning it off explicitly).  Also...if it is an intermittent error (I have prod databases in SQL Azure and less that 1% connections fail), make sure you are using the retry policy block for connection resiliency.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue this morning, I could connect to my sql azure instance from my machine, could log in through the sql azure management portal but not through my azure website.

the solution in the end was to go into the dashboard for the azure website and add the database as a linked resource.

not very obvious and maybe a coincidence but for the time being it works.

Comment: Thanks, but my database is already added to the cloud service as a linked resource. The issue is just happening intermittently, so I feel like some kind of transient condition might be in play.