# Can two Azure SQL databases on the same server affect each other's performance?

Tags: azure-sql-database

Let's say I have two Azure SQL databases, DB1 and DB2, on the same server, blah.database.windows.net. Can high traffic against DB1 affect the performance of DB2?

Background: I started getting several transient SQL errors (timeouts, pre-login handshake failures) on a hosted service talking to DB2 during a time when I had a different hosted service hitting DB1 with excessive traffic (LINQ-to-SQL deletes against hundreds of thousands of records individually). Unexpectedly, the errors on DB2 disappeared once I corrected the high traffic against DB1. I wouldn't have expected this, since as I understand from [this article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1541.windows-azure-sql-database-connection-management.aspx):

> A SQL Database server is a logical group of databases.

What shared resource could there be, if any, between these two DBs? Can traffic going against one Azure SQL DB affect the performance of other DBs on that same server, or is this more likely to have been a coincidence? I know that they *may* reside on the same physical server, but didn't expect that to be likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the DBs are in the same server, they share the hardware resources. If one monopolizes the resources, it starves the others.

in your case, it might be your other DB (assuming they both got provisioned in the same physical server) or other tenants on the same server doing some heavy processing.

Comment: This shoudn't happen with new SQL DB performance tiers and resources are reserved per database.

Comment: @SirishaChamarthi are you sure this is the case? We've seen similar effects as user1454265 with the new S1 tier.